# Custom Gradle Plugin get an error after trying to apply my plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a very simple Gradle plugin and share it to my other project using my local maven repository, however i am getting an error when I am trying to apply the plugin in my consumer app.

Plugin `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.mendix"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("test-plugin") {
            id = "com.mendix"
            implementationClass = "com.mendix.TestPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer app that is trying to use the plugin `build.gradle.kts`

```
apply(plugin = "TestPlugin")

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.mendix:TestPlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    `maven-publish`
}
```

After I perform `gradle publishToMavenLocal` I am able to see the plugin in my .m2 folder, however I find it interesting that the name of the plugin is camelcase.
[image]
But when I am trying to apply the plugin on my consumer app I got the following error:
`Plugin with id 'TestPlugin' not found.`

Could you enlighten me what could be the problem here?

Comment: The id of your plugin is `com.mendix` so you'll need `apply(plugin = "com.mendix")` for a start